# Apply the same random colour change to background AND border

Tags: jquery

I have two hexagon divs. I have muddled my way through some jQuery to create a function that will randomly choose from two colours to decide a div's background colour. The problem is, I would also like the top and bottom border of my hexagon to change to the respective colour of it's body. I am using the :before and :after pseudo-elements to create my hexagon and can't get my function to apply to them. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var randomColors = ["#96281B","#F7CA18"];
    $(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).css("backgroundColor",randomColors[randomNum]);
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show what I already have: http://jsfiddle.net/k7eo7r1m/

Comment: Do you mean "top and bottom border" or "top and bottom regions"?

Comment: @GabeKopley the top and bottom regions ARE the top and bottom border. They are dimensionless in the sense that the border is what creates their visual shape

Comment: You can't manipulate the styles of CSS pseudo elements with JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work the way you're imagining. There's no way to directly target `:before` or `:after` pseudo classes using Javascript, since technically it is not part of the DOM.

Comment: @APAD1 say I were to make them their own divs with separate classes, say "top" and "bottom", would it be possible that way?

Comment: Yep, go with Lochemage's solution below. Define the different colors in separate classes and then apply the classes at random using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to just set up CSS class names for each color, then just add the appropriate class to the hexagon.

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can change the CSS of an ':after' element because they don't actually exist in the DOM, so you can't get access to it.

EDIT: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7eo7r1m/9/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomColors = ["","altColor"];
    $(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 57.74px;
    background-color: #F7CA18;
    margin: 28.87px 0;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 28.87px solid #F7CA18;
}

.hexagon:after {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 28.87px solid #F7CA18;
}

.altColor {
    background-color: #96281B;
}

.altColor:before {
    border-bottom: 28.87px solid #96281B;
}

.altColor:after {
    border-top: 28.87px solid #96281B;
}
```

EDIT2: I've cleaned up the CSS.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're saying by that first sentence. Sucks about not being able to target the pseudo elements though. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you have a CSS class name for each color alteration you want, then you randomly choose between one of those names and apply it to your hexagon (in my example the class names are .normColor and .altColor).

Answer (score 0):

It works with class names and colors for border and background. See http://jsfiddle.net/k7eo7r1m/10/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var randomColors = ["borderYellow","borderBrown"];
$(".hexagon").each(function(index) {
    var len = randomColors.length;
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
    // remove all other possible set color-classes
    // $(this).removeClass(randomColors.join(' ')); // optional, e.g. if you like to change colors at runtime
    // add a random new one
    $(this).addClass(randomColors[randomNum]);
});
});



/* colors */
.borderYellow{
    background-color: #F7CA18;
}
.borderYellow:before,
.borderYellow:after{
    border-color: #F7CA18;
 }
.borderBrown{
    background-color:#96281B;
}
.borderBrown:before,
.borderBrown:after{
    border-color: #96281B;
}
/* Boxes, Shapes ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new additional styles **dynamically**. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/01y97u0c/)

```
$.each(randomColors, function(_, color) {
    var className = getHexagonClassName(color);
    $('<style>.' +
      className + '{background-color:' + color + ';}.' +
      className + ':before{border-bottom-color:' + color + ';}.' +
      className + ':after{border-top-color:' + color + ';}</style>')
    .appendTo($('head'));
});
```